# Error at runtime

Tags: prolog

I must find the  permutations which  have 2 consecutive elements whose difference is less than 3.

```
cons2Less3(L,Rd):-
    findall(R, (permute(L,R),(isValid(R))), Rd).

isValid([H|T]):-
    listContainsConsecLess3(T,H).

listContainsConsecLess3([H|_],C):-
    4 > abs(H - C),!.
listContainsConsecLess3([H|T],_):-
    listContainsConsecLess3(T,H).

permute(L,Rd):-
      findall(R, (perm(L,R)), Rd).

perm([],[]).
perm([E|L],Z):-
    perm(L,Z1),
    elim(E,Z,Z1).

elim(E,[E|X],X).
elim(E,[A|X],[A|Y]):-
    elim(E,X,Y).
```

But at runtime:

Debug:

```
  1 = [[6, 3, 6], [6, 6, 3], [3, 6, 6], [6, 3, 6], [6, 6, 3]]
  2 = [3, 6, 6]
```

Console:

```
ERROR: >/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[3,6,6]' ("x" must hold one character)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `permute(L, R)` returns a list of lists in `R`. Then you call `isValid(R)` on a list of lists, which means `H` in the expression `abs(H - C)` is a list, which is not valid syntax. Get rid of the `findall` in your `permute` predicate and let it return results one at a time via backtracking. Why don't you use Prolog's `permutation/2` predicate?

Comment: It is requested from me to do it this way...

Comment: OK. You shouldn't be using `findall` in your `permute/2` implementation.

Comment: checked, it works, make it an answere if you would like so that i accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This diagnosis is that the code has "findall-itis". :)

You're starting with this:

```
cons2Less3(L,Rd):-
    findall(R, (permute(L,R),(isValid(R))), Rd).
```

Which assumes that `permute/2` will *generate* each permutation individually upon backtracking. However, your `permute/2` also calls `findall/3`:

```
permute(L,Rd):-
      findall(R, (perm(L,R)), Rd).
```

So `perm/2` generates individual permutations on backtracking, but then `permute/2` gathers them into a list. Thus, you end up calling `isValid(R)` with `R` being a lists of lists, and then:

```
isValid([H|T]) :-    % Called with [H|T] a list of lists
    listContainsConsecLess3(T,H).   % Called with T a list of lists

listContainsConsecLess3([H|_],C):-  % Called with H a list
    4 > abs(H - C),!.               % H is not numeric, but a list!
...
```

Leads to the numeric expression `abs(H - C)` having `H` as a list which yields your error.

The quick fix is to get rid of `permute/2` and just call `perm/2` directly:

```
cons2Less3(L,Rd):-
    findall(R, (perm(L,R), isValid(R)), Rd).
```

Comment: All findalls that are not safely guarded against too general goals should really be banned.